Provide free or pay updates
I developed a simple IoT device. It has a built-in HTTP webserver to set the general options of the system. Now the customer asks for "in-app" updates, that might be delivered free of charge or after purchasing them.
Here my thoughts:

the server that hosts the website of the product will handle all the e-commerce stuff
the server will provide a REST service so my device can ask which packages are available for download
the server itself has to check (given the device ID) which packages are free to download and which were purchased by the user
in this way I can list the available packages on my built-in web app, download them directly (i.e. from FTP) and store them into the ESP32 flash

My question is: I believe I can implement this workflow from scratch, but I'm not an expert in security and I'm afraid I can make dumb mistakes providing critical flaws. Is there a protocol or at least some standardized guidelines to provide such a feature for IoT devices?
It's not a life-critical system. I'm not looking for a very high security standards. But as said I want to avoid newbie mistakes.
Not sure which tags are more appropriate for this question. Please feel free to edit it!
